# General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61 flutter

Tags: android, flutter, semantics

Facing this issue in flutter after i updated the android version Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1.

General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

changed the Jvm version.according to my gradle 6.7